# How to add ratio of two columns in an another column having it's own values in line break pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame ...

```
data = {'Col1': [232, 348, 649], 'Col2': [1500, 1550, 1600], 'Col3': [330, 290, 668]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I want to add ratio of Col1 & Col3 to Col2 in respective rows of Col2 as a new line as below...

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
232     1500     330
      (0.70)
348     1550     290
      (1.20)  
649     1600     668
      (0.97)
```

How to do that plz ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using string operations and [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/):

```
from tabulate import tabulate

print(tabulate(
        df.assign(Col2=df['Col2'].astype(str)+'\n('
                  +df['Col1'].div(df['Col3']).round(2).astype(str)
                  +')'),
        headers='keys', tablefmt='plain')
     )
```

Or:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

print(tabulate(
        df.assign(Col2=df.apply(lambda r: f'{r["Col2"]}\n({round(r["Col1"]/r["Col3"], 2)})', axis=1),
        headers='keys', tablefmt='plain')
     )
```

Output:

```
      Col1  Col2      Col3
 0     232  1500       330
            (0.7)
 1     348  1550       290
            (1.2)
 2     649  1600       668
            (0.97)
```

Comment: Sir how to drop index column plz

Comment: Sir getting output like this in script having lambda operation.Plz remove keys & plain...

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV03r.jpg

Comment: @Brijesh add `showindex=False` as parameter to `tabulate`.

Answer (score 3):

If it's for visual purposes, you can try this :

```
def ratio_of(c1, c2, at="Col2"):
    return (df[c1].div(df[c2]).map(
            lambda v: f"({v:.2f})").to_frame(at))

out = (pd.concat([
    df.astype("O"), ratio_of("Col1", "Col3")]).reset_index()
           .sort_values(["index", "Col2"], ignore_index=True)
           .drop(columns="index").fillna(""))
```

Output :

```
print(out.to_string(index=False))

Col1   Col2 Col3
 232   1500  330
     (0.70)     
 348   1550  290
     (1.20)     
 649   1600  668
     (0.97)
```

Comment: I want output like this. Ratio can be inserted in smaller font size..


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW82X.jpg

Comment: There is not really a "font size" in pandas, please clarify which exact dataframe pocket object you'd expect as output.

Comment: I mean to say Col2 must has same index level more clearly no. of rows should be same as in Col1&Col3.

Answer (score 2):

Please create a list, add a new row in the for loop, and then convert it to DF at the end.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': [232, 348, 649], 'Col2': [1500, 1550, 1600], 'Col3': [330, 290, 668]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Ratio'] = df['Col1'] / df['Col3']
result_data = []

# add each row and new line with ratio
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result_data.append(row)
    result_data.append(pd.Series({'Col1': '', 'Col2': f'({row["Ratio"]:.2f})', 'Col3': ''}))

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_data)
result_df = result_df.reset_index(drop=True)
result_df = result_df.drop('Ratio', axis=1) #drop ratio

print(result_df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Col1    Col2   Col3
0  232.0  1500.0  330.0
1         (0.70)
2  348.0  1550.0  290.0
3         (1.20)
4  649.0  1600.0  668.0
5         (0.97)
```

Comment: I want output like this. Ratio can be inserted in smaller font size..


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW82X.jpg